# Quick way to perform speech recognition of very short vocabulary in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios5, speech-recognition

I am programming an app for research purposes. I need a quick way to perform speech recognition of very small vocabulary (as small as 5 words in the entire dictionary). I know of many speech recognition frameworks like OpenEars, ATT Watson Speech API, Dragon etc. But it requires you to invest a lot of time in reading. 
Since the focus of our app is not speech recognition, we want to do it in a quick way. I know that if I have only 5 words, then I can replace them with 5 choices as well, but that is not appropriate. 
Any ideas on this? Thank you.

Comment: Did you actually try to write some code?

Comment: I have and I succeeded using iSpeech's API. Also, I did not want to try openEars and others because I have done my literature survey and I know they will be time consuming for me because I am a beginner. Our app is only for research purposes and thus I wanted to know if there is any quick way since trying complex stuff will not be useful. I will post the code shortly.

Comment: Maybe you want to read the rules of this website first before posting another senseless question

Comment: I know the rules. You need not worry about me posting senseless questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenEars developer here. OpenEars has a quickstart tutorial that can get you started recognizing a small vocabulary in about 5-10 minutes: http://www.politepix.com/openears/tutorial

Answer (score -1):

if you don't bother of non iOS, then Voxforge can be a good starting point.

http://www.voxforge.org/home/downloads

I also get many help from this site with HTK when I wrote thesis.
this web site contains training procedure step by step which will be good for you.

hope this can help in small vocabulary speech recognition.

(HTK itself has sample training procedure for 10 digits)